# Docker compose - Name or service not known when calling service from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Django app in one container, trying to compose it with Redis and Mysql containers. However, calling

```
redis://redis:6379
```

from Django app, gives me

```
ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting redis://redis:6379. Name or service not known.
```

I do not see any difference in my setup, compare to other working solutions. Do I miss something?
My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.production_cs 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: eprofi
    volumes:
      - .:/eprofi
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db:postgres
      - redis:redis
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=django_app
      - MYSQL_USER=django_app
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=django_app123
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

My Dockerfile

```
# We Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7.13
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# The enviroment variable ensures that the python output is set straight
# to the terminal with out buffering it first
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# create root directory for our project in the container
RUN mkdir /www

# Set the working directory to /www
WORKDIR /www

#Upgrade pip
RUN pip install pip -U

#Install dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /www/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /www
ADD . /www/
```

Then I do

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Everything starts as expected, but calling Redis with "redis://redis:6379" gives the above "Name or service not known." error.

My tools

```
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
docker-py version: 2.5.1
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.4
```

**UPDATE 1**
How I call Redis from python app (old Django).

Settings of Django app:

```
CACHES = {
    'my_cache': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://{}:{}'.format(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT),
        'KEY_PREFIX': 'project/my_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 60*60*24,  # expire in 24 hours
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB': 1,
            'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection.HiredisParser'
        }
    },
}
```

Call:

```
cache = get_cache('my_cache')
cache.get(cache_key)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Command

```
ping redis
```

run in the container gives me an error

```
ping: unknown host
```

Comment: how you create the connection in python script?

Comment: do `ping redis `works from django container ? I think also the connection in django should use something as `r = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)`

Comment: Container of redis is running without errors (see `docker ps`)? Redis ready to accept connections (see `docker logs <id of redis-container>`?

Comment: The `links:` block is unnecessary, but in sort of the some networking space.  Does removing it help at all?

Comment: @Adiii I added UPDATE 1 to the question where is the code of the connection to Redis.

Comment: @LinPy ping redis in container gives me an error "ping: unknown host"

Comment: @LinPy Can there be the problem in old Django? It's 1.5 version.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue with the V2 release of Docker Compose introduced in Docker Desktop. For now, simply unchecking the option solves the problem in my case.
[image]
Not sure if this is because links are going to be deprecated in docker-compose or not, it seems that the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) still lists the command without deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

The `links` option is deprecated according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). In order the services to call each other, they should be on the same network. So for your example the solution is something like this. You can learn more about network [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    ...
    networks:
      - my_network
  db:
    ...
    networks:
      - my_network
  redis:
    ...
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

Comment: no, you dont need to setup an external network for that to work. compose will create it for you by default

Comment: Yeah sure, this is just an example

Comment: You don't need _any_ `network:` declarations for this to work.  Compose will create a `default` network for you and attach all of the containers to it.

Comment: @VassilisPallas yeah, this does not solve the problem, but ty

Comment: @user3024710 ok I see. Well this is too strange. Did you try to restart the docker service, or stop and remove the redis service from the composer and run it again?